# Saving responses of questions individually or batch wise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

I am working towards an idea of a Q & A site . Looking to implement the question part of the application using ember or angular so that the user doesn't reloads the page on next question . I have built the application on rails partially but now i am thinking whether i should be saving the responses on each question or do them all together at the end .A particular user can answer 100 questions at a go . As i am new to ember and angular frameworks , any suggestions will be highly appreciated . Also there is supposed to be a point system which displays the score in the later stages . What all gems or plugins i can use to make the development a bit faster .

Gems already used -
Devise

Pundit

rails_temporary_data

ember_rails

angular_rails (Have used ember and angular in 2 separate applications)

Answer (score 0):

you can either use HTML5 session/web storage. Its simple. Here you can find a comparison between session vs web storage - `http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/`

Or you can use HTML5 IndexDB. Its fairly new but very convenient. checkout `http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/`

Comment: I am using postgresql , will it not be possible with it ?